# Recommended walking miles for sedentary person

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, flexibility, walking

I am 37 and almost all my while I sat in front of a computer (always had a bear belly) with little to no activity or sometimes regular gym and sometimes nothing but now I am having pain in my knees when I stand up in the kitchen to do some cutting my knee feel swelled when climbing stair and next day I have heavy knees.

I did start walking which does make things better but I want to find out recommended walking miles for a sedentary person as is walking the best course of action to turn things around for me (as I see it, I have inherited this problem as my mother n another sibling have it too)

Comment: I don't have a number to give you, but I would recommend applying the 10% rule (usually used in running) to avoid going too hard all at once. Don't increase your weekly distance by more than 10%. If you are currently walking a mile 3 times a week, maybe next week try 1.1 mile three times or 3 * one mile and then 0.3 miles on a fourth day.

Comment: If you've been sedentary for a number of years, you should talk with your personal physician before undertaking any form of physical fitness.  They know your personal history and can give you the 'green light' on exercise.